# 'SQLite Error: No Such Table' with TypeORM on a connected DB with other tables accessible. Is there a specific way to reach tables with foreign keys?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

Good evening all,

I am trying to query on a table called 'MessageEntityXREF' stored on a sqlite DB through TypeORM.

The database is connected and other tables are reachable.

When I try to Get on this specific table:
"QueryFailedError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: message_entity_xref"

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried to change the order in the constructor, changed the typing.
However, considering the same method works for other tables, I tend to think there is an issue with this table.
I queried the sqlite db for a list of all tables, it gives a list with the MessageEntityXREF in it.
I installed DB browser for SQLite and the table is here with the MessageID and EntityId columns.

NOTE: there is a table called "Entities" in the database which could lead to confusion with TypeORM tendency to use @Entity etc...

With nestJS, I created an entity for this table and I inject the repository in a custom service used then by a function which find in this repository:

Messages Service

```
@Entity export class MessageEntityXREF {

@PrimaryColumn() MessageId: number;

 @Column() EntityID: number; } 


custom service

@InjectRepository(MessageEntityXREF)
private readonly messageEntityRepository: Repository<                 MessageEntityXREF>

async getMessagesByEntityId(id: number): Promise<any[]> {
try {
  return await this.messageEntityRepository.find({
    select: ['MessageId','EntityId'],
    where: [
    { EntityId: id}
    ]
 });
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
  }
 }
}
```

I would expect a list of all MessageId with a given EntityID.

When no ID is given, I get an empty array (expected).

When I give an ID, I get a 500 error from the server with "QueryFailedError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: message_entity_xref"

Definition of entity

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class MessageEntityXREF {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  MessageId: number;

  @Column()
  EntityId: number;
}
```

Messages Module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register(),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Messages, MessageEntityXREF]),
  ],
  providers: [MessagesService, MessagesResolver],
  controllers: [MessagesController],
})
export class MessagesModule {}
```

and the ormconfig.json

```
{
  "skip": false,
  "name": "default",
  "type": "sqlite",
  "database": "./sqliteDB/solve.rld",
  "entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "logging": false
}
```

Comment: Did you include your entity in the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` import?

Comment: Hello Kim,
I did include the entity in :
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Messages, MessageEntityXREF]),

in my messages module.
And in app module, I imports :
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
.

I can reach the 'Messages' table.

Comment: Weird, if I try to connect to a new table, let say SimulationTimes, by connecting to the repository in a custom service, it will also says that the tables doesn't exist.
And it still works for 'old' tables....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Weird flex.

In my entity definition, I let @Entity() empty

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class MessageEntityXREF {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  MessageId: number;

  @Column()
  EntityId: number;
}
```

and then typeORM is requesting the sqlite db for the table "message_entity_xref".
Instead of MessageEntityXREF.

Forcing it like that:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('MessageEntityXREF')
export class MessageEntityXREF {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  MessageId: number;

  @Column()
  EntityId: number;
}
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the cause was different. In order to make TypeORM work with SQLite I needed to add `synchronize: true` to TypeORM options:

```js
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: path.resolve(__dirname, '../db.sqlite3'),
      entities: [User, Post],
      logging: true,
      synchronize: true,
    })
```

Comment: READ THIS:
**synchronize - Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data. This option is useful during debug and development.**

Comment: Most likely the database file did not exist, and synchronize created the file